# Viewing The Interactive Cypress Test Runner In Docker On Linux

Tags: linux, docker, cypress

I'm trying to see Cypress in interactive mode when the Cypress tests are running in a docker container.  This article explains how do it on Mac - https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/05/02/run-cypress-with-a-single-docker-command/#Interactive-mode.  I cannot get it to work however on my new linux mint OS install.

Following the article, I have set -

```
$ IP=172.17.0.1
$ xhost + $IP
$ export DISPLAY=172.17.0.1:0
```

Which is the IP address on my local host machine on the Docker default bridge network.

This is my only set up.  Next is the docker command for running the container -

```
docker container run -it \
  -v $PWD:/e2e \
  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
  -w /e2e \
  -e DISPLAY \
  --entrypoint cypress \
  cypress/included:3.8.1 open --project .
```

The only difference is the latest image and 'docker container run' instead of the deprecated 'docker run ...'

It elicits -

> (Cypress:16): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 172.17.0.1:0

Now the article does warn this may come up -

> **Debugging tip:** if Cypress shows an error Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:... make sure X11 server allows connections over the network from the Docker container. Run xhost command in the terminal to see if it has the IP address you have added previous with xhost + $IP.

When I run -

```
$ xhost
```

It gives -

> INET:ross-Aspire-TC-780
>
> SI:localuser:ross

I'm a hobby web dev with not much sys admin knowledge so I was totally relying on the article working.  Does anybody know how to get this working?

Comment: That `xhost` invocation is dangerous: there is an extra space that completely disables host-based access controls.  Setting `-e DISPLAY=:0` and not running `xhost` _might_ work; but running graphical applications in Docker isn't straightforward, and you might find it easier to run this task without Docker.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I'm afraid it didn't work.  I'll bear in mind your advice about xhost.  The problem is I'm developing a django app - don't know if you know django - and it has a nice feature whereby it will start a development server during tests (create a separate db, listening on a different port etc) so I need to run the web app in a docker container so it links to my postgres container and everything else.  That brings to mind a question though ... how easy is it to replace a docker service yet have this replacement still use the docker services?

Comment: ...(continuation from last comment).  So the web app now running outside docker still accesses the docker services?  Postgres db etc

Comment: Very easy: use Docker Compose `ports:` or a `docker run -p` option for the databases _etc._, and your application under development on the host outside of Docker can access them using `localhost` as a host name and the published port number.

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming/code questions. I suggest to visit https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```
docker run -it --rm \
    --network host \
    -v ~/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:ro \
    -e DISPLAY \
    -v $PWD:/e2e \
    -w /e2e \
    --entrypoint '' \
    cypress/included \
    npx cypress open
```

To run any GUI application in a `docker` container you've got to understand how X Window System works. X uses client-server model. An X server program runs on a computer with a graphical display and communicates with various client programs (X clients). The X server acts as a go-between for the user and the client programs, accepting requests for graphical output from the client programs and displaying them to the user (display), and receiving user input (keyboard, mouse) and transmitting it to the client programs.

In X, the server runs on the user's computer, while the clients may run on remote machines. This terminology reverses the common notion of client–server systems, where the client normally runs on the user's local computer and the server runs on the remote computer. The X Window terminology takes the perspective that the X Window program is at the centre of all activity, i.e. the X Window program accepts and responds to requests from applications, and from the user's mouse and keyboard input. Therefore, applications (on remote computers) are viewed as clients of the X Window server program.

[image]

So, to run a GUI application in a docker container, you've got to provide a way for it to communicate to the X server running on the host. One way to go about it is to use `host` networking (`--network host`). In this case the container shares the host's networking namespace. I.e. container’s network stack is not isolated from the Docker host. Particularly, the container can connect to any servers running on the host.

Also, you've got to let the container authenticate to the X server. Again, one way to achieve this is to use cookie-based authentication. For that you've got to share the `~/.Xauthority` file with the container (`--volume ~/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:ro`).

And you've got to tell the container where the X server is running. For that the [`DISPLAY` variable](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/X.7.html#sect4) is used. Since the container is going to have access to the host's network namespace, you can simply pass the `DISPLAY` variable from the host into the container (`--env DISPLAY`).

Then you need to make sure the tests are available for `cypress` (`--volume $PWD:/e2e` + `--workdir /e2e`).

Additionally, `cypress/included` sets the entrypoint to `cypress run`, so to open `cypress` you've got to reset the entrypoint (`--entrypoint ''`), and use `npx` (`npx cypress open`), or else it won't find your project files. Usually, you run `cypress` located at `./node_modules/.bin/cypress`, but `cypress` in the image resolves to `/usr/local/bin/cypress`. `npx` makes it run `cypress` from the `./node_modules` dir.

That is not needed in case of `cypress run` because the latter [defaults](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/v3.8.1/cli/lib/exec/run.js#L129) to the current dir. For one reason or another `cypress open` [doesn't do that](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/v3.8.1/cli/lib/exec/open.js#L9) if installed globally.

As such,

```
docker run -it --rm \
    --network host \
    -v ~/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:ro \
    -e DISPLAY \
    -v $PWD:/e2e \
    -w /e2e \
    --entrypoint '' \
    cypress/included \
    npx cypress open
```

More on it [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/645258bc55023ed0392d4b2559113121).

P.S. If you do anything memory intensive, `cypress` (or rather `chrome`) might occasionally crash. That happens because by default `docker` allocates 64 MB for shared memory (`/dev/shm`). One way to remedy this is to give the container access to the host's shared memory. In other words, to unisolate the IPC namespace. That is achieved by passing `--ipc=host`. That's [not something specific to `cypress`](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/350#issuecomment-267704772). What crashes is basically `chrome`.

Comment: Hi, thanks your response.  The 'cypress/included:latest' image cannot be found however so I ran the docker container with 'cypress/included:3.8.1'.  Although it did open up in interactive mode in the docker container printed to the console it says - ' Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory'.  Also the Chrome browser testing is flaky.  Most of the time the browser crashes for myself.  Although the Electron browser seems ok always.  Do you get this yourself?  I may need to report both to Cypress.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1849962 For all I know, "Failed to connect to dbus" has no practical consequences. As for the crashes, see the added "P.S." section.

Comment: To get around the SHM limit, and not have to open up the hosts's IPC, I have been doing my docker run with the option:     --shm-size 512M

Answer (score 5):

Great answer provided by @x-yuri and it pointed me in the right direction to solve my problem.

For people struggling to get this running with Docker compose and Ubuntu, here is the stripped off version of my docker-compose.yml.

The key property is `network_mode: host`.

Run `xhost +local:` first to ensure correct permissions are set.

```
version: '3'
services:
  back-office-web-app:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ../build:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - 3000:80
  e2e-tests:
    image: cypress/included:4.8.0
    working_dir: /e2e
    entrypoint: cypress open --project /e2e
    depends_on:
      - back-office-web-app
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      CYPRESS_VIDEO: 'false'
      CYPRESS_BASE_URL: 'http://localhost:3000'
      DISPLAY:
    volumes:
    - ./test/:/e2e
    - ~/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw
```

Answer (score 0):

For me works:
-> change display to 0:0:
`export DISPLAY=0:0`
-> then:
`xhost +`
-> set up a display to proper one:
`export DISPLAY=$IP:0`
-> and launch docker container :)|

Comment: I'm not sure If i could understand your steps, could u write it as a bash script?